# Is it possible to restore an ubuntu guest vm but keep home directory data untouched?(on Virtualbox or other virtual machine solution)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is it possible to restore an ubuntu guest vm to an earlier snapshot and keep home directory data from restoring?

Or to say keep the user directory out of the system  vdi to prevent data loss after screw a system?

EDIT: I've tried write-through vdi on windows 7 guest earlier, but often randomly lost some new files and sometimes even old files corrupted. Have no idea it's a problem of Windows or Virtualbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  When you create your VM you'll want to create a separate virtual disk for your home directory data.  In the VirtualBox Virtual Media Manager (File -> Virtual Media Manager) find your home directory disk and select "Modify" and change the mode to "Writethrough".

From the [VirtualBox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#hdimagewrites):

> By contrast, write-through hard disks are completely unaffected by
>   snapshots: their state is not saved when a snapshot is taken, and not
>   restored when a snapshot is restored.