# VirtualBox write-through drive not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I have a VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu installed on normal VDI, and I added another write-through VDI so that I could keep my code intact when I switch between different system snapshots which I use for testing.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/750411/341852), any changes I make to the write-through disk are supposed to persist between snapshots. However, it doesn't seem to work - the changes I make to the write-through drive get rolled back as if it was a normal drive.

Here's how I've been testing it so far:

1. Attached the drive to the VM in VirtualBox. VirtualBox reports the drive type to be wrote-through.
2. Booted the VM and mounted the drive in `/home/dev`. If I open this folder's properties, I get free space reported for the write-through drive, so I safely assume it was indeed mounted correctly where I wanted it.
3. Created a test file on the write-through drive and made a snapshot.
4. Created another file alongside the first and made another snapshot.
5. Reverted VM back to snapshot created in step 3. The second file I put on the write-through drive is now gone, as if it was a normal drive instead of a write-through one. Refreshing or re-opening the folder didn't help.

I also tried executing `sync` command after creating the files, in case the changes were staying cached and weren't actually written to the disk, but it didn't really change anything.

I read somewhere that there could be problems with write-through disks if there were shared folders attached to the VM, which I do have (two of them in fact). I tried disconnecting those and testing again, but it still wouldn't work.

Did I miss some important step while setting up the second drive? Or do I simply fail to understand how write-through drives are supposed to work and I was doing it wrong all along?